# Inserir uma opção no select em um determinado indice

Tags: javascript, html-select

Possuo o seguinte select:

```
<select id="selectChannelCam" class="custom-select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
</select>
```

Como podem ver, possui apenas uma opção que não é nem selecionável. Eu gostaria de adicionar novas opções, mas de forma ordenada.
Ordenar é facil, mas eu preciso inserir em um índice especifico, pois é possivel que seja necessário inserir por exemplo, o canal 2 antes do 1.

---

Já tentei:

```
$('#selectChannelCam :nth-child(' + index + '))').after("<option value='" + keys[0] +"'>" + keys[0] + "</option>");
```

e

```
$("#selectChannelCam :nth-child(" + index + ")").append(new Option(keys[0], keys[0]));
```

Comment: As opções vêm de onde?
Não tem já um Array de Opções e depois apenas as insere por ordem?

Comment: Elas dependem de uma outro cadastro. Quando o usuario cadastrar um canal, esse canal deve ser adicionado a esse select. Pego tudo de um arquivo

Comment: Então tem como objetivo adicionar opções dinamicamente usando um arquivo para guardas as opções cadastradas pelo usuario, correto?

Comment: Exatamente. Já consegui colocar essas opções em um vetor, falta adicionar ao select (pois no arquivo há outras informações tambem, então achei melhor já colocar no vetor)

Comment: Pode ordenar esse vetor antes e quando for popular o select será apenas inserir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `eq(n)` para selecionar o número do índice, e em seguida `before()` ou `after()` para inserir o novo elemento antes ou depois respectivamente.

Veja esse exemplo:

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#selectChannelCam option").eq(2).before($("<option>Uma nova opção</option>").text("Nova Opção"));   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectChannelCam" class="custom-select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<p>
   <button id="btn">Inserir valor</button>
</p>
```

O `eq(2)` seleciona o elemento com índice 2, e insere um novo option antes (`before`).

Comment: como faço para que as opções sejam variaveis em vez de um texto chumbado?

Comment: é só fazer como no seu exemplo que tem `+ index +` por exemplo

Answer (score -1):

**Como inserir uma opção num elemento Select:**

```
// referência para elemento select
var sel = document.getElementById('selectChannelCam');

// criar um elemento opção
var opt = document.createElement('option');

// Aqui atribui o valor de texto que tem guardado no seu vetor
opt.appendChild( document.createTextNode('Texto que aparece na sua Opção') );

// Aqui atribui o valor da opção que tem guardado no seu vetor
opt.value = 'option value'; 

// Adicionar a opção ao final do elemento select
sel.appendChild(opt);
```